# Can anyone help me translate this Lancashire dialect phrase 'O Full True un Pertikler Okeawnt...'

Tags: phrases

O Full True un Pertikler Okeawnt o wat me un maw mistris un yerd wi’ gooin to th’Greyte Eggshibishun e’Lundun.

Thank You!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the source of this expression?

Comment: @KillingTime This is quoted from It's a Don's life by Mary Beard: Why research is fun, KT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence quoted [*It's a Don's Life* by Mary Beard](https://books.google.com/books?id=kunPs4xyG3wC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=okeqwnt&source=bl&ots=U-0kh_pCC3&sig=ACfU3U0zBxbTo8roOeJtwrGiUHGljQdjyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQzIqEirTlAhVnUd8KHUewB3gQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=okeqwnt&f=false) says it is a satirical account of going to the Great London Exhibition:

> A full true and particular account what me and my mistress did (done/have) hear(d) while going to the Great Exhibition in London.

It's a quote from [*Vissit to Th' Greyte Eggshibishun*](https://books.google.com/books?id=e5BzZC6WiSQC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=un+yerd&source=bl&ots=EgBVFL_uJ0&sig=ACfU3U29LzrUHk7ePd519ONVKtazFKJJ6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5_N32irXlAhVSmuAKHarPAAMQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=un%20yerd&f=false)

*Okeqwnt* is a typo in Beard. The original text says *Okeawnt* which is more recognizable as account.

Mistress here likely refers to his employer rather than his paramour ...

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank You !

Comment: I checked the orginal book Mary Beard quoted from, it's "okeawnt".

Comment: @DavidM I think it's _A full, true and particular account of..._

Comment: @KateBunting YES!!!!!!

Comment: I'm termpted to think that "e'Lundun" is _in London_ rather than _of London_.

Comment: I would also say _e’Lundun_ should be ‘in London’, and I think _un yerd_ should be ‘have heard’, rather than ‘did hear’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet un yerd is more like done heard to my mind. But like most translations the gist is much more important than a word for word parity.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Please see my edit.

Comment: Very true! (To get the gist, it is of course also worth noting that _mistress_ here presumably refers to the man’s wife, the missus – not, as it would nowadays, to someone with whom he’s having an extramarital affair.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Or even his employer ... He might be a servant.

Comment: Also not unlikely.

Comment: I'd actually go as far as to say more likely than wife.

Comment: Could “un yerd” be “endured”?  In *It’s a Don’s Life* did they hear something notable or was it an account of everything that happened on the way?

Comment: @Jim Not likely. Look [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=e5BzZC6WiSQC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=un+yerd&source=bl&ots=EgBVFL_uJ0&sig=ACfU3U29LzrUHk7ePd519ONVKtazFKJJ6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5_N32irXlAhVSmuAKHarPAAMQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=un%20yerd&f=false) at the original source. Yerd is used for heard in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidM - Yep.  I see. Thanks.